# Sparkcontext stopped inside listener

Tags: java, apache-spark, listener, mysql-connector

I want to create one dataset at end of spark program and save that dataset to MYSQL. I am using listener to listen for job end and inside that I am doing the creating and saving of dataset.

The listener is

```
SparkListener sparkListener=new SparkListener() {
    @Override
    public void onJobEnd(SparkListenerJobEnd jobEnd) {
        try{
            TimeUtils.saveParameterData(sparkSession,appNameSplit,batchJobRunId,moduleName);
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
        super.onJobEnd(jobEnd);
    }
};
sparkSession.sparkContext().addSparkListener(sparkListener);
```

The saveParameterData method has the save like this

```
try{
    //the error occurs at this line
    df.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(url,"Time_Count_Stats",connectionProperties);
 }catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

The connection properties is

```
Properties connectionProperties=new Properties();
connectionProperties.setProperty("user","***myusername****");
connectionProperties.setProperty("password","****mypassword****");
connectionProperties.setProperty("driver","com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
```

This gives me the error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call methods on a stopped SparkContext.

I have been trying to resolve the error but can't find a solution. Can anyone help?

Comment: I don't have access to the main code. I only have access to helper code(which does read and write). The stats which I am trying to save are related to my helper function and I want that save to happen only once (at the end). Hence, I am using listener to listen to the end of application.

Comment: The stats are like start time of read, end time of read, number of records read, the query string which ran. I am storing that info, and creating and saving the dataset which contains these info. The code is long and there are many files, so can't post.

Comment: listeners are fire and forgot, As soon as job completed spark will stop its session & so you cannot use or spark session migh not available for long time inside ```onJobEnd```.. may be you can check other listener methods or use pure scala code write data to database.

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to look at other ways but none has helped till now.

Comment: just workaround.. write your states sysout or logfile.. once your job is done read data from log & update into your database.